# Client Side Validation Not Working With Foreign Keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Client side validation is not working for me for foreign keys only.

I have

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

included as well as

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

set in my web.config file.

There are no custom attributes or anything. It's something as simple as

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Fiscal year is required")]
[Display(Name = "Fiscal Year")]
public int FiscalYearId { get; set; }
```

Any ideas on this? I've searched for a solution, but all I have found are cases where it does not work at all and most solutions say to make sure the two above scripts are sourced and the two above keys are added to the web.conifg file.

I am getting no js errors and I have monitored with firebug. Everything appears to work perfectly, but it obviously is not.

Once I correct the non-foreign key fields and resubmit, data validations do work server side. This is an issue because it is creating a double validation and annoys the hell out of the users.

Help is much appreciated.

Below is the Html portion. It is contained in a using block. It's standard MVC3 generated CRUD code.

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="FiscalYearId">Fiscal Year</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <select id="FiscalYearId" name="FiscalYearId">
        <option value="">---Select Fiscal Year---</option>
        <option value="1">FY2013</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FiscalYearId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you inspect and post the generated HTML on the FiscalYearId dropdown? Also, make sure your form element is within a `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { }` block.

Comment: updated my question with the html

Comment: Yes, select has no validation attributes, this is not javascript problem

Comment: @karaxuna what do you mean select has no validation attributes?

Comment: Rendered select html must be like this in order to be validated: <select id="FiscalYearId" name="FiscalYearId" data-val="true" data-val-required="Fiscal year is required"> ... Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no metadata attributes rendered in html. Try this in your view:

```
if (this.ViewContext.FormContext == null) 
{
    this.ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext(); 
}
```

Comment: I did try this, no luck, however.

Comment: Is html you have posted inside Html.BeginForm?